# Can I get multiple booster packs from one game?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

Is it possible to get multiple booster packs from the same game? I've just got one that I sold on the market and now I can't even find the game listed in the badges page on my profile.

Comment: Please re-check if the game is on the badges page. Also: Which game?

Comment: [It's not there](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197989922965/badges). Super Meat Boy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've gotten two Booster Packs for Bit.Trip Presents: Runner2: Future Legend of Rhythm Alien!, though I opened, rather than sold, both of them.

Make sure you don't accidentally have a sort set for your badge page.

At the very least, you're not limited to a single booster pack per game.

Answer (score 1):

I received two booster packs, and both games are still in my badges list. If I open the info popup of those games, it says that I'm still eligible for booster packs.

EDIT: A game is shown in the badge page if either:

- You have still drops.
- You have at least one card of that collection.
- You played it recently.

For example Dota 2 wasn't showing in my badge page, since I don't have any card and I already used all drops. I started it and now it shows up in my badge page. Start Super Meat Boy and it will be shown.

Comment: Have you sold any of your booster packs? I've sold the Super Meat Boy Booster Pack which isn't in my list anymore but I got the Skyrim Booster Pack too which I have in my inventory and in the list.

Comment: Starting it did the trick.